# How to split a text column in to a list containing all rows?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe column containing words in different rows:

```
**Word**
Word1
Word2
Word3
```

But I want a list that will other wise be created as

```
    list <- C("Word1","Word2","Word3"...)
```

I am sure there is a quick and simple way to do it, I am just not able to figure it out.

The following code works fine:

```
myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(master$Content))
#master$Content is nothing but a text column with statements as entries.

myTDM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(minWordLength = 3))

words <- C("Word1","Word2","Word3")
corr <- c(0.7, 0.75, 0.1)

# returns a list
my_assocs <- findAssocs(myTDM, words, corr)
```

but it does not work when I try to make a list of the words from the Dataframe column and rerun the findAssocs.

I get this error:

```
> my_assocs <- findAssocs(myTDM, as.list(wordlist[,1]), corr)
Error: is.character(terms) is not TRUE
```

Comment: @docendodiscimus I think the question is not clear for to be duped for `as.list`

Answer (score 0):

If we needed a `list`, then use `as.list` on the column

```
as.list(df1$Word)
```

Otherwise, if it is a `vector`, then one of the many options can do

```
df1$Word
df1[["Word"]]
df1[, "Word"]
```